# Backbone collection.create not triggering 'add' event

Tags: events, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm struggling with a simple backbone/coffeescript example. I'm trying to add a Question to the QuestionList and have it fire an 'add' event on the collection so I can render it. I'm using the create method since I am trying to have it connect to my server, here modelled by the console.

In this example the console prints "create: {"question":"Question","answer":"Answer"}" but not "Event occurred" as expected. What am I doing wrong here?

```
jQuery ->
    class Question extends Backbone.Model
        defaults:
            question: 'Question'
            answer: 'Answer'

    class QuestionList extends Backbone.Collection
        model: Question

        initialize: ->
            @bind 'all', -> console.log "Event occurred"

    Backbone.sync = (method, model) ->
        console.log method + ": " + JSON.stringify(model)

    question_list = new QuestionList

    question_list.fetch()

    question_list.create 
                    question: $('#question').val()
                    answer: $('#answer').val()
```

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the part of the code you posted, because there aren't any evident mistaskes in your code, and the event is firing and handled just fine (on Backbone 0.9.9). See this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nW7ne/

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: Thanks Fencliff, hearing it worked for you but didn't for me made me realise I was using a much older Backbone from a tutorial I found. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The version of Backbone being used was old since I'd downloaded a tutorial and continued working from there. Upgrading to Backbone 0.9.9 solved the issue. (thanks Fencliff!)